# get active cell without using macro

Tags: excel, selection, undo

I need to get the address of the active cell in cell A1

I can do it woth a macro

```
Sub Worksheet_selectionchange(target as range)
Cells(1,1)=activecell.address
End sub
```

The problem with this solution is that the user looses the undo...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the formula

```
=CELL("address")
```

By omitting the second argument, it will give you the address of the activecell. The address will only change on calculate, not just when you move the selection. I also remember hearing that it's unreliable when the active sheet is not the sheet with the formula. If you can't live with those limitations, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: If only the reculc was automatic... this was exactly what I need. Thanks this ability is interesting...but i guess as you said i'm out of luck :)